# Strange JavaFX Application Thread exception

Tags: javafx

We are making a card game named Dominion with client-server, using Java Serialization. We are working also with observer/observable and threads (threads for reading messages on server and client side).

We are highlighting the card with CSS if a player is able to play or buy a card. The highlight is added by the update methode of the interface Observer where a gamecard is being observed. If a specific condition is true, we will add the highlight to the gamecard (class GameCard is implements Observer).

In general it works fine, but there is a card (named Militia) which forces the opponents to discard cards from their hand until they got only 3 cards left. We can play this for several times without exceptions, but suddenly there are several exceptions (after about 7-10 times played the Militia cards). We have no idea why.

What could be the reason of this exceptions? I think it doesn't help if I post the code, I will post the exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:755)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:140)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.computeLocalBounds(Node.java:3595)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateLocalBounds(Node.java:3625)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1524)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3643)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.getChildTransformedBounds(Parent.java:1732)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1596)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_intersectsBounds(Node.java:5015)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_pickNodeLocal(Region.java:2931)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_pickNode(Node.java:4914)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3899)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:1942)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$6700(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3711)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3579)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3532)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3480)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_intersectsBounds(Node.java:5015)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_pickNodeLocal(Region.java:2931)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_pickNode(Node.java:4914)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3899)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:1942)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$6700(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3711)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
```

**...and if we just mouse hover over the stage, it throws hundreds of times this exception:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Code which could cause the exceptions:
1. in this class we highlight the cards which the opponent has to discard (until he has left 3 cards; see line where croupier.isDiscardModeMilitia....)

```
public class GameCard extends Button implements Observer  {
    protected static final boolean MoneyCard = false;
    ServiceLocatorClient sl = ServiceLocatorClient.getServiceLocator();
    Croupier croupier = Croupier.getCroupier();

    Label   lbl_cardName;
    String text_DE;
    boolean holeCard  = false;

    int costs;

    StackSizeInfo stackSizeInfo;


    public GameCard(Label cardName, String text_DE) {
        super();
        this.lbl_cardName = cardName;
        this.text_DE=text_DE;
        this.assignPicture();
    }

    public GameCard(){
    }

    GameCard gc = this;

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {

        getStyleClass().remove("highlight");
        getStyleClass().remove("highlight2");
        getStyleClass().remove("highlight3");

        //Highlighte alle Karten im Kaufmodus, welche ich mit der aktuelln Buypower und buys kaufen kann
        if (croupier.isBuyMode() == true && croupier.getBuyPower() >= this.costs && !this.isHoleCard() && croupier.getBuys() > 0){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Geldkarten im Kaufmodus
        if (croupier.isBuyMode() == true && this.isHoleCard() && this instanceof MoneyCard){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Aktionskarten im Aktionsmodus
        if (croupier.isActionMode() == true && this.isHoleCard() && this instanceof ActionCard){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        }

        //Highlighte alle HoleCards im Discardmodus (basement)
        if (croupier.isDiscardMode() == true && this.isHoleCard()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle HoleCards im TrashModus Kapelle
        if (croupier.isTrashModeChapel() == true && this.isHoleCard()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle MoneyCards im TrashModus Mine
        if (croupier.isTrashModeMine() == true && this instanceof MoneyCard && this.isHoleCard()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Karten auf der Hand, welche im Umbaumodus weggeworfen werden können
        if (croupier.isTrashModeRebuilding() == true && this.isHoleCard()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Kupferkarten auf der Hand, die gegen +3Geld weggeworfen werden können (ActionCard Geldverleiher)
        if (croupier.isTrashModeMoneylender() == true && this.isHoleCard() && this.getLbl_cardName().getText().equals("copper")){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle MoneyCards, welche erworben werden können im Minen-Modus
        if (croupier.isModeForMine() == true && this instanceof MoneyCard && !this.isHoleCard() && this.costs <= croupier.getSavedMCValueForMineMode()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Karten zum Kauf, welche erworben werden können im Rebuilding-Modus
        if (croupier.isModeForRebuilding() == true && !this.isHoleCard() && this.costs <= croupier.getCardValueForRebuildingMode()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Karten zum Kauf, welche erworben werden können im Rebuilding-Modus
        if (croupier.isModeForWorkshop() == true && !this.isHoleCard() && this.costs <= 4){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Moat-Karten wenn ein Angriff gemacht worden ist
        if (croupier.isReactionMode() == true && this.isHoleCard() && this.getLbl_cardName().getText().equals("moat")){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight3");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Moat-Karten wenn ein Angriff gemacht worden ist
        if (croupier.isDiscardModeMilitia() == true && this.isHoleCard()){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight2");
        }

        //Highlighte alle Moat-Karten wenn ein Angriff gemacht worden ist
        if (croupier.isModeForCurseCard() == true && !this.isHoleCard() && this.getLbl_cardName().getText().equals("curse")){
            this.getStyleClass().add("highlight2");
        }

        //wenn stacksize auf 0, wird highlighting ebenfalls deaktiviert
        if (croupier.getStackSize(gc) == 0) {
            this.getStyleClass().remove("highlight");
        }

        //update das STackSize infoLabel auf der Karte      
        if (this.stackSizeInfo != null){

            stackSizeInfo.updateStackSizeInfo();

        }


    }




    public void assignStackSizeInfo(){
        stackSizeInfo = new StackSizeInfo(gc,croupier.getStackSize(gc));
    }




    public void assignPicture(){
        if (this.holeCard == false)
            this.getStyleClass().addAll("card_mini",lbl_cardName.getText());
        else 
            this.getStyleClass().addAll("card",lbl_cardName.getText()+"_big");
    }




    public boolean isHoleCard() {
        return holeCard;
    }

    public void setHoleCard(boolean holeCard) {
        this.holeCard = holeCard;
    }

    public Label getLbl_cardName() {
        return lbl_cardName;
    }

    public String getText_DE(){
        return this.text_DE;
    }

    public void setLbl_cardName(Label lbl_cardName) {
        this.lbl_cardName = lbl_cardName;
    }   
}
```

2. possible code fragment: here we are updating the GUI. This happens whenever we play a card from the hand. We will remove it first from the LinkedList (HoleCards) in another method and then we call updateGUI

   public void updateGUI() {

   ```
           // Zeichne holeCards Neu
           hb_wrapper_holeCards.getChildren().clear();
           for (int i = 0; i < croupier.getHoleCards().size(); i++) {
               GameCard gc1 = croupier.getHoleCards().get(i);

               try{
                   hb_wrapper_holeCards.getChildren().add(gc1);
                   gc1.setPrefSize(160, 260);
                   gc1.setMaxWidth(160);
               }catch (NullPointerException e){
                   //
               }


           // Zeichne Ablagekarte neu
           hb_wrapper_stapel.getChildren().clear();
           dummyCardAblagestapel.getStyleClass().clear();
           try {
               String cssSelector = new String(croupier.getAblagestapel().peekLast().getLbl_cardName().getText()+"_big");

               dummyCardAblagestapel.getStyleClass().addAll("card",cssSelector);
               hb_wrapper_stapel.getChildren().addAll(dummyCardAblagestapel,nachziehstapel);   
           } catch(Exception e){
               hb_wrapper_stapel.getChildren().addAll(this.dummyCardAblagestapel,nachziehstapel);  
               }           
           }

       }
   ```

**note1: I guess it happens in the first fragment where we highlight the cards. After a player has discarded cards until he has only 3 left in the hand, we will remove the highlight. Exactly when he discards his last card, the exception is thrown (but as I said, we can play this for about 7-10 times without exceptions, but suddenly the exceptions are thrown)**

**note2: I have already tried with Platform.runLater on this 2 code fragments and it didn't help**

Comment: Post the code that causes the exception. Probably this is a threading issue (e.g. you are modifying the UI from a background thread).

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Comment: That's the problem, we don't know which line causes the exceptions, but I have posted the code fragments which could cause the exceptions (see first post)

Comment: @JoelHenz I guess what I meant was you should create a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem. You can see all your code; we can't; so it's highly unlikely we can help. It *looks* like a threading issue; if you are randomly adding `Platform.runLater()` in places to see if it fixes problems you are already lost. You have to write code that *ensures* you *always* update the UI from the FX Application thread. If you don't actually know which thread your UI code is running on, your best bet is likely to be to scrap the entire project and start again from scratch, imho.